# Ionic: save camera images to device and upload later

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I am building an app that uses the cordova-camera plugin. right now I was able to access the device camera and get the file URL..

I want to store the image and the image path to localstorage and the  and use it later for uploading when the device becomes online.

here's my code so far

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePhoto = function(){
    var element = event.target;
        var options = {
          quality: 75,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          allowEdit: true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 100,
          targetHeight: 100,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
          correctOrientation:true
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imageURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            angular.element(element).closest('.input-group').find('.input-container').val($scope.imageURI)
            console.log(angular.element(element).closest('.input-group').find('.input-container').attr('id'));

        $cordovaFile.moveFile(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, imageData, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory)
              .then(function (success) {
                console.log('success')
              }, function (error) {
                console.log(error)
              });

        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
    console.log();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="factory_gate" class="label-control">Factory Gate</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-container" id="factory_gate" ng-model="factory_gate" placeholder="">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-success" type="button" ng-click="takePhoto($event)">
                <i class="icon ion-android-camera"></i>
            </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how can I achieve my output? I have installed the cordova file plugin already..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so once you have the file URL all you have to do is store it and a good option is https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage. You may have to stringify it to store properly so check it has been stored properly by using `log` then use http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/ to upload the image once the device is online. Any problems lemme kno.